# How to configure SOCKS5 together with DNS through SOCKS5 using pure Windows APIs in Poweshell

Tags: windows, powershell, socks

Is there any way to configure Windows to redirect all internet traffic through a SOCKS5 tunnel (unauthenticated) without any third party tools (i.e. Proxifier, Freecap, etc.) and without dealing with any UI (purely using command line) in such a way that DNS resolution would be also pushed through the tunnel (similar to what Proxifier does)?

DNS resolution cannot be done by changing the Lan Settings in the Internet Options

I have tried `netsh winhttp set proxy` and it didn't work (the IP address did not change to the one associated with the SOCKS tunnel)

I also tried using the `route` command, but it turned out that it does not support port configuration.

Comment: Windows does not have a feature to proxify ALL traffic. That is why such 3rd party tools exist in the first place.

Comment: @RemyLebeau: Is there a free CLI application that can do this?

Comment: asking for tool recommendations is off-topic for StackOverflow.

Comment: @RemyLebeau: Oh sorry for asking for that! Now what happens next? Do I go to prison for breaking that law? I really don't understand people that act like robots.

Comment: Try asking in [Software Recommendations](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com) or [sf]